# Solving heat equation in the given form which satisfy certain conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I'm trying to solve the following heat equation:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = m\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} \\
u(0,x) = f(x) \\
u(t,0) = u(t, L) = 0
\end{align}
where $m > 0$ The question asks us to find all solutions of the form $u(t,x) = \exp(-\lambda t)f(x)$ where $\lambda \in R$. I get that $ u(0,x) = exp(0)f(x) = f(x)$ is always met so we can ignore this condition. And $u(t,0) = u(t,L) = f(x) \Rightarrow f(0) = f(L) = 0$. Substituting $\frac{du}{dt} = m\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$, we get that $f''(x) = -\frac{ \lambda}{m}f(x)$. I then tried to take different cases of $\lambda$. So we get that if $\lambda = 0$ then $f(x)$ is constant which is not possible. However, if $\lambda != 0 $, we either get real or complex roots. Suppose $\lambda < 0$, then we would get real roots for the second order differential equation $f''(x)$ so it will be of the form $f(x) = c_{1}e^{\sqrt{-\frac{\lambda}{m}}x} + c_{2}e^{-\sqrt{-\frac{\lambda}{m}}x}$. Now since $f(0) = 0$, we get that $f(0) = c_{1} + c_{2} = 0 \Rightarrow c_{1} = -c_{2}.$ Also since $f(L) = 0$, we get that $f(L) = c_{1}e^{\sqrt{-\frac{\lambda}{m}}L} + c_{2}e^{-\sqrt{-\frac{\lambda}{m}}L} = c_{2}\left(e^{-\sqrt{-\frac{\lambda}{m}}L} - e^{\sqrt{-\frac{\lambda}{m}}L}\right) = 0 \Rightarrow c_{2} = 0$ so $c_{1} = 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ and $U(t,x) = 0$. Could somebody please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: 1. Use \ partial (without the space) to get $\partial$, \ mathbb{R} to get $\mathbb{R}$ and \ ne to get $\ne$ 2. You have some typos. The equation you have above is an ODE with no spatial derivatives, I'm guessing you wanted $m \partial_{x}^{2} u$. Also, you also have the boundary and initial conditions as $u(\color{red}{t,0}) = f(x)$ and $u(t,0) = u(t,L) = \color{red}{f(x)}$. So you might want to fix up.

Comment: Just fixed the edit to the correct initial condition.

Comment: The correct initial condition would be $u(\color{blue}{0}, \color{red}{x}) = f(x)$.

Comment: Yep,also could you expand on the point you made. It's not clear to me how I should approach this problem.

Comment: I think you really need to just take a minute and fix the post in full, there are still many typos. Also, the statement 'if $\lambda != 0$, we either get $\dots$ when taking into account the initial conditions $f(0) = f(L) = 0$' doesn't make sense to me. I can tell you that the nontrivial solution to $f'' = \color{red}{-} \lambda f/m$ exists when $\lambda > 0$ and $f = A \sin(n \pi x/L)$

Comment: Sorry for my clumsiness. I fixed the question (I think) and expanded upon the point I was trying to make.

Comment: What you have included to your post for the case $\lambda < 0$ is correct. Now do the $\lambda > 0$ case.

Comment: As @mattos says, the solutions that you seek are on the road not yet taken. The computation of the case $λ>0$ is as difficult as the previous case $λ<0$.